# Sorted linked list inserting duplicates at each execution

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a function that reads data from a file, then inserts in increasing order based on a specific field from each row of data.

If I compile and run this section of code, it sorts initially, but once I repeat the action, I get a sorted duplicate, if I run one more time, each item appears 3 times.

How can I make this code stop inserting duplicates ?

```
void sortData(Node *& head, Node * data)
{
    ifstream fin("data.txt");
    int acc; string fname, lname; double bal;
    while (fin >> acc >> fname >> lname >> bal)
    {
        data = new Node;
        data->account = acc;
        data->fname = fname;
        data->lname = lname;
        data->balance = bal;
        data->next = NULL;

        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = data;
        }

        else if (data->balance <= head->balance)
        {
            data->next = head;
            head = data;
        }

        else
        {
            Node * temp1 = head;
            Node * temp2 = temp1->next;

            while (temp2 != NULL && data->balance > temp2 ->balance)
            {
                temp1 = temp2 ;
                temp2 = temp2 ->next;
            }

            data->next = t2;
            temp1 ->next = data;
        }

    }

    Node * temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        cout << temp->account << " " << temp->fname << " " << temp->lname << " " << temp->balance << "\n";
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    fin.close();

}
```

Clarity.

The program runs with a simple MENU, so when I build and run the first time, I can do several things, insert a new record, delete, show all records(where issue is), then exit. I can repeat each actions as many times as possible, expect Exit (obviously).

Initial Run, then show all records according to account number:

1111 FName1 LName1 400.56

2222 FName2 LName2 23.45

3333 FName3 LName3 4599.91

4444 FName4 LName4 1000.5

Works well.

But

When I want to show all records again, I see this

1111 FName1 LName1 400.56

1111 FName1 LName1 400.56

2222 FName2 LName2 23.45

2222 FName2 LName2 23.45

3333 FName3 LName3 4599.91

3333 FName3 LName3 4599.91

4444 FName4 LName4 1000.5

4444 FName4 LName4 1000.5

I'm not reinserting into the file, just printing out data in increasing order.

Comment: Please post your main. I think you call sortData n times, and therefor you read the data from file n times, which is why you will have n copies after n invocations. However I need to see your main to confirm this.

Comment: A note no code formatting, here on SO. 4 spaces is used to denote 'this is code' So imagine 4 spaces disappear from each line, in the final output.

Comment: @viktoriaAnderson do you want to help?

Comment: @d14, I think you need to post the code/function that inserts new nodes to the list. The logic to determine when a duplicate is encountered and then to not insert a new node if one exists must be in that code/function.

Comment: In order to not insert duplicates, you have to check first if its a duplicate, and then not insert it. Another way could be to always start with a empty list. Btw, what's wrong with `std::list`?

Comment: You're loading the same file into your list with each call to this function. And you state, "...but once I repeat the action..." - why are you repeating this action? You already loaded the file into the list. If the file is updated and you want to reload it you can certainly do so, but the criteria for inserting a new node via *identity* had better be based on more than just your apparent primary sorting field (`balance`). Or do you believe it realistic that two different accounts can never have the same `balance` value? I certainly don't.

Comment: @RSahu et al,  Clarity added to question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing too many things in one function. Divide them up into smaller, reusable functions.

```
// Function to insert the data sorted in an order.
void insertSortedData(Node*& head,
                      int acc,
                      std::string const& fname,
                      std::string const& lname,
                      double bal)
{
   // If the list is empty, create a node and return.
   Node* newNode = new Node(acc, fname, lname, bal)
   if ( head == NULL )
   {
      head = newNode;
      return;
   }

   // If the value of the new node is less or equat to the value
   // of the head node, make it the head node and return.
   if (newNode->balance <= head->balance)
   {
      newNode->next = head;
      head = newNode;
      return;
   }

   // Insert new node at the right place.
   Node * temp1 = head;
   Node * temp2 = temp1->next;

   while (temp2 != NULL && newNode->balance > temp2->balance)
   {
      temp1 = temp2 ;
      temp2 = temp2->next;
   }

   newNode->next = temp2;
   temp1->next = newNode;
}
```

---

```
// Function to read data from a file and create
// a sorted list.
void readDataFromFile(std::string const& file,
                      Node*& head)
{
   std::ifstream fin(file);
   int acc;
   std::string fname;
   std::string lname;
   double bal;
   while (fin >> acc >> fname >> lname >> bal)
   {
      insertSortedData(head, acc, fname, lname, bal);
   }
}
```

---

```
// Functoin to print the contents of a list.
void printList(Node* head)
{
   Node* temp = head;
   while (temp != NULL)
   {
      cout << temp->account << " " << temp->fname << " " << temp->lname << " " << temp->balance << "\n";
      temp = temp->next;
   }
}
```

Then, you can call each one separately:

```
int main()
{
   Node* head = NULL;

   // Read data from a file.
   readDataFromFile("data-1.txt", head);

   // Print the data
   printList(head);


   // Read data from a different file.
   readDataFromFile("data-2.txt", head);

   // Print again.
   printList(head);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact that your function does too much, and even without seeing the calling code, I can tell from your output - if what you show is in fact the only output - that you call `sortedData` multiple times. `sortedData` inserts all entries from the input file in a sorted manner every time `sortedData` is called, independent of whether they are there already or not! So after n calls, you have n copies of a data element in your list.

Think about what you want your function to do. Right now your function does this **on EVERY CALL**:

`while` there are more entries in the input file:

1. Read the next entry from the input file.
2. Insert the entry into the list in a sorted manner.

You now have a sorted list of all entries in the input-file. You print all entries in the list.

After the return the list-head you passed into the function still points to the valid list containing all the entries you just read.

If you only want to display all entries, the only thing you have to repeat 
is the printing part, but if you invoke `sortedData` again, you will instead repeat the entire function and this time the List you pass is not empty, but already contains every entry from the input-file, so adding every entry again in a sorted manner will give you a duplicate for every entry. So the simplest solution for you is to call your function once on startup, and to just call a `printList()` function later, which simply does the printing part:

```
void printList(Node *head){//local copy of the pointer, can change this
    while (head != NULL)
    {
       cout << head->account << " " << head->fname << " " << 
           head->lname << " " << head->balance << "\n";
       head = head->next;
    }
}
```